# Can a quadratic be solved with matrices?

Tags: matrices, quadratics

The question, pure curiosity, is whether you can solve a quadratic with the use of matrices?

And if yes, does that method also work for higher polynomials?

Say for example I have a quadratic such as written below:
\begin{equation}
x^2+3x+2=0
\end{equation}
By simple other known methods, one ends up with $x = -1$ or $-2$.

(I already know it is possible to find the solution of a system of simultaneous equations... Maybe does that help?)

Can you get to those results with matrices? Thanks a lot for your contribution and answers!

Comment: I don't think so, at least not in a more or less "natural" way, as far as I can see. What you can do with matrices is to classify two-dimensional or three-dimensional quadratics, and to find out whether some given quadratic by means of the symmetric matrix determined by its coefficients, and the matrix's determinant, signature, etc.

Comment: matrices are usually used to solve linear equations.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do use matrices here: we are given the problem
$$
u^2 + 3u + 2 = 0
$$
substituting $u = x/y$, we have
$$
x^2/y^2 + 3x/y + 2 = 0 \implies\\
x^2 + 3xy + 2y^2 = 0 \implies\\
\pmatrix{x&y} \pmatrix{1&3/2\\3/2&2} \pmatrix{x\\y} = 0
$$
this is now a problem about [quadratic forms](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form), which can be solved using knowledge about symmetric/Hermitian matrices.

This particular method doesn't extend to higher degree polynomials.

---

Another approach: the zeros of a polynomial are precisely the eigenvalues of the associated [companion matrix](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).  This works for polynomials of any degree.

In your particular case, we can find the zeros of $x^2 + 3x + 2$ by finding the eigenvalues of the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&-2\\1&-3\\}
$$

Comment: Matlab, for example, finds the roots of a polynomial (numerically) by constructing the companion matrix and computing its eigenvalues.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That is extremly useful to know! Thanks a lot!